# "CryptographicException: Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 0." Cannot decrypt saved data

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, serialization, aes

I'm developing a game using Unity engine. Currently, I'm on my very first journey to creating a secure and universal game data saving/loading. My game is able to succesfully save its data (game progress) and metadata (custom savable types, encapsulating the data, and necessary for succesfull data deserialization) into two files, but when it comes to loading the data, a weird error occurs upon decoding. It appears a really weird one to me because I googled similar error topics but wasn't able to find a satisfying answer.

The error and its stacktrace are:

> CryptographicException: Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 0.
> Mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.ThrowBadPaddingException (System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode padding, System.Int32 length, System.Int32 position) (at <9aad1b3a47484d63ba2b3985692d80e9>:0)
> Mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.FinalDecrypt (System.Byte[] inputBuffer, System.Int32 inputOffset, System.Int32 inputCount) (at <9aad1b3a47484d63ba2b3985692d80e9>:0)
> Mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.TransformFinalBlock (System.Byte[] inputBuffer, System.Int32 inputOffset, System.Int32 inputCount) (at <9aad1b3a47484d63ba2b3985692d80e9>:0)
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock () (at <9aad1b3a47484d63ba2b3985692d80e9>:0)
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing) (at <9aad1b3a47484d63ba2b3985692d80e9>:0)
> System.IO.Stream.Close () (at <9aad1b3a47484d63ba2b3985692d80e9>:0)
> System.IO.StreamReader.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing) (at <9aad1b3a47484d63ba2b3985692d80e9>:0)
> System.IO.TextReader.Dispose () (at <9aad1b3a47484d63ba2b3985692d80e9>:0)
> AuxMath.Decode (System.String input, System.Security.Cryptography.Aes decoder, System.Text.Encoding encoding) (at Assets/Scripts/Misc/AuxMath.cs:191)
> SavingSystem.TryLoadMetadata (System.Security.Cryptography.Aes decoder, System.Text.Encoding encoding) (at Assets/Scripts/Saving System/SavingSystem.cs:164)
> Rethrow as Exception: Metadata loading failed!
> SavingSystem.TryLoadMetadata (System.Security.Cryptography.Aes decoder, System.Text.Encoding encoding) (at Assets/Scripts/Saving System/SavingSystem.cs:180)
> SavingSystem.Load () (at Assets/Scripts/Saving System/SavingSystem.cs:82)
> SavingSystem.Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/Saving System/SavingSystem.cs:43)

My saving/loading.

```
private void Save()
{
    Aes encoder = Aes.Create();
    encoder.Key = _keyContainer.Key;

    PrepareSavableData();
    SaveGameData(encoder, Encoding.UTF8);
    SaveMetadata(encoder, Encoding.UTF8);

    SavegameCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private bool Load()
{
    Aes decoder = Aes.Create();
    decoder.Key = _keyContainer.Key;

    if (TryLoadMetadata(decoder, Encoding.UTF8) && TryLoadGameData(decoder, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The key for encryption is created randomly using default Aes settings and stored inside a KeyContainer ScriptableObject.

Here is the actual saving.

```
private void PrepareSavableData()
{
    foreach (var entity in _registeredEntities)
    {
        _storedStates[entity.ID] = entity.GetState();
    }
}

private void SaveMetadata(Aes encoder, Encoding encoding)
{
    using FileStream fileStream = new(MetadataPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    using StreamWriter writer = new(fileStream, encoding);

    List<string> knownTypesNames = new(_knownSavableDataCustomTypes.Count);

    foreach (var type in _knownSavableDataCustomTypes)
    {
        knownTypesNames.Add(type.ToString());
    }

    string data = AuxMath.SerializeObjectToString(knownTypesNames, encoding);
    string encodedData = AuxMath.Encode(data, encoder, encoding);

    writer.Write(encodedData);
    writer.Close();
}

private bool TryLoadMetadata(Aes decoder, Encoding encoding)
{
    if (File.Exists(MetadataPath))
    {
        try
        {
            using FileStream fileStream = new(MetadataPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using StreamReader reader = new(fileStream, encoding);

            string encodedData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string decodedData = AuxMath.Decode(encodedData, decoder, encoding);

            var knownTypesNames = AuxMath.DeserializeStringToObject<List<string>>(decodedData, encoding, _knownSavableDataCustomTypes);
            HashSet<Type> knownTypes = new(knownTypesNames.Count);

            foreach (var typeName in knownTypesNames)
            {
                knownTypes.Add(Type.GetType(typeName));
            }

            _knownSavableDataCustomTypes.UnionWith(knownTypes);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Metadata loading failed!", e);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private void SaveGameData(Aes encoder, Encoding encoding)
{
    using FileStream fileStream = new(SavegamePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    using StreamWriter writer = new(fileStream, encoding);

    string data = AuxMath.SerializeObjectToString(_storedStates, encoding);
    string encodedData = AuxMath.Encode(data, encoder, encoding);

    writer.Write(encodedData);
    writer.Close();
}

private bool TryLoadGameData(Aes decoder, Encoding encoding)
{
    if (File.Exists(SavegamePath))
    {
        try
        {
            using FileStream fileStream = new(SavegamePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using StreamReader reader = new(fileStream, encoding);

            string encodedData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string decodedData = AuxMath.Decode(encodedData, decoder, encoding);

            _storedStates = AuxMath.DeserializeStringToObject<Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>>(decodedData, encoding, _knownSavableDataCustomTypes);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Game data loading failed!", e);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'm using DataContractSerializer to convert custom object types with a valuable game data to XML string representation in preparation for encoding/decoding.

```
public static string SerializeObjectToString(object obj, Encoding encoding)
{
    if (obj is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(obj)}", "Cannot serialize a null object!");
    }

    using MemoryStream memoryStream = new();
    using StreamReader reader = new(memoryStream, encoding);
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new(obj.GetType());

    serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, obj);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}

public static T DeserializeStringToObject<T>(string objectAsXml, Encoding encoding, IEnumerable<Type> knownTypes)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objectAsXml))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(objectAsXml)}", "Data is empty!");
    }

    if (knownTypes is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Known types are not supplied! Deserialization will fail!", $"{nameof(knownTypes)}");
    }

    using MemoryStream memoryStream = new();
    byte[] xmlAsBytes = encoding.GetBytes(objectAsXml);
    DataContractSerializer deserializer = new(typeof(T), knownTypes);

    memoryStream.Write(xmlAsBytes, 0, xmlAsBytes.Length);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    if (deserializer.ReadObject(memoryStream) is T value)
    {
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Passed data is invalid or corrupted and cannot be restored!");
    }
}
```

Finally, encoding and decoding. Encryption algorithm gets a new initialization vector on every encoding. It gets written unencryptedly directly into the stream, before the encrypted stream writes the secured data. Upon decryption it is necessary to read 16 bytes first from the stream, as they represent the decryption initialization vector.

```
public static string Encode(string input, Aes encoder, Encoding encoding)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(input)}", "Attempted to encode an empty input!");
    }

    if (encoder is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(encoder)}", "Encoder is not set!");
    }

    encoder.GenerateIV();

    using MemoryStream memoryStream = new();
    using CryptoStream encodingStream = new(memoryStream, encoder.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    using StreamWriter encodedWriter = new(encodingStream, encoding);

    memoryStream.Write(encoder.IV);
    encodedWriter.Write(input);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    encodedWriter.Close();

    return encoding.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
}

public static string Decode(string input, Aes decoder, Encoding encoding)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(input)}", "Attempted to decode an empty input!");
    }

    if (decoder is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(decoder)}", "Decoder is not set!");
    }

    using MemoryStream memoryStream = new();
    memoryStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(input));

    byte[] iv = new byte[decoder.IV.Length];
    memoryStream.Read(iv, 0, decoder.IV.Length);
    decoder.IV = iv;

    using CryptoStream decodingStream = new(memoryStream, decoder.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    using StreamReader decodedReader = new(decodingStream, encoding);

    return decodedReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Maybe reset the stream position before you start reading from it?

Comment: This line, `return encoding.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());` doesn't make sense and will corrupt the data. Encrypted bytes are not the encoding of a string, therefore you should not attempt to decode them to string. If you absolutely must have a string for some reason then you can base64 encode after encryption and base64 decode prior to decryption.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk 1) The data was indeed corrupted. When I compared old and new save files the difference is noticeable by eye. 2) I decided to simplify as much as possible and got rid of strings in favor of byte arrays, and also got rid of encoding parameters completely. 3) I refactored serialization to use byte arrays as well. 4) I use binary writers/readers with backing crypto streams alongside file streams when necessary, but on decoding the same error occurs. It is basically the same line as before: `return decodedReader.ReadBytes(input.Length - decoder.IV.Length);`

Answer (score 0):

The following code both works perfectly and is a lot shorter:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input, KeyContainer container)
{
    byte[] iv = container.GetNewIV();

    using SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = Aes.Create();
    using ICryptoTransform encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(container.GetKey(), iv);

    List<byte> output = new(iv.Length + input.Length + algorithm.BlockSize / 8);
    byte[] encryptedInput = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length);

    output.AddRange(iv);
    output.AddRange(encryptedInput);

    algorithm.Clear();

    return output.ToArray();
}

public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] input, KeyContainer container)
{
    byte[] iv = input[..KeyContainer.IVLength];
    byte[] encryptedInput = input[KeyContainer.IVLength..];

    using SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = Aes.Create();
    using ICryptoTransform decryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(container.GetKey(), iv);

    byte[] output = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedInput, 0, encryptedInput.Length);

    algorithm.Clear();

    return output;
}
```

1. Instead of referring to an Aes instance directly a more generalized SymmetricAlgorithm must be used because AES is one of the implementations of a symmetric encryption.
2. Instead of trying to perform cryptographic transformations implicitly by using ICryptoTransform as a backing resource inside a stream, one must be performed by calling TransformFinalBlock() method.
3. After all the crypto activity is done, any memory containing valuable data must be overridden by calling the Clear() method on a symmetric algorithm instance. This way hackers cannot recower any data to attempt and actually succesfully decrypt the result.